# Password creator not outlogging the expected output

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I am currently trying to make a password creator, just to get some pratice. However I have run into a problem. When I try to console.log my password, it outputs undefined, no error messeages. I think it has something to do with my for loop in my generatePassword function, however I don't see the problem myself.

**JavaScript**

```
const randomFunc = {
    lower: getRandomLower,
    upper: getRandomUpper,
    number: getRandomNumber,
    symbol: getRandomSymbol
}

const passwLength = 20;

function generatePassword() {
    for(let i = 0; i < passwLength;) {
        let password = randomFunc.lower; randomFunc.upper; randomFunc.number; randomFunc.symbol;
        i++
        console.log(password)
    }
}

function getRandomLower() {
    return String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 97);
}

function getRandomUpper() {
    return String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 65);
}

function getRandomNumber() {
    return String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 48);
}

function getRandomSymbol() {
    const symbols = '!"#¤%&/()=@£$€{[]}|*^~+-,.;:<>|§';
    return symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length)];
}
```

Comment: Well, what exactly are you expecting `let password = randomFunc.lower; randomFunc.upper; randomFunc.number; randomFunc.symbol;` to do?

Comment: I'm sorry if I am unclear, but I was expecting that to output some random lower and upper case letters with some numbers and symbols between all of it, so it would look like one of those automated passwords :)

Comment: Then it should be `let password = randomFunc.lower() + randomFunc.upper() + randomFunc.number() + randomFunc.symbol();`.

Comment: Also note that you might need to initialize the `randomFunc` variable **after** you declare all of those functions.